# what does this notation `:>` mean in Coq?

Tags: coq

I saw `:>` notation being used inside a record datatype definition. 
Not sure if this is a standard notation or if it is defined somewhere in the file I am looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It declares a coercion from the record to that field.

For example, if you have a record:

```
Record foo :=
  { f1 :> bar
  ; f2 : baz
  }.
```

If you have `x : foo`, then you can put it somewhere where a `bar` is expected, and an application of `f1` will be automatically inserted.

```
x : bar
(* will desugar to (f1 x : bar), though it will still be hidden by Coq's prettyprinter. *)
```

For more details, see the manual: https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/addendum/implicit-coercions.html#classes-as-records